# Correct prepositions to use with "risk of/for ABC for XYZ"

Tags: prepositions

In a scientific medical context I need to talk about "risk" in various contexts. Two exemplary phrases each with a separate meaning are:

1. the risk of having ABC
2. risk that having ABC causes XYZ

To the former I refer to as "risk of ABC", now it seems strange to me to refer to the latter as "the risk of ABC for XYZ". As  a non-native speaker it is hard for me to assess whether the latter would convey the correct meaning. Better suggestions are welcome

Comment: (I am aware of this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356385/different-uses-of-risk-of-to-for-in-professional-medical-literature-style, but it does answer my question)

Comment: In your second version, *the risk that having ABC causes XYZ* is unusual phrasing which I would interpret as referring to the *possibility* that ABC *does in fact* cause XYZ. Which may or may not be true, but from the speaker's perspective  it would be a bad thing if there were such a causal link. This is significantly different to the first statement, which simply asserts that having ABC is an (undesirable, but possible) condition, irrespective of whether this leads to XYZ.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that these two have substantially different meanings. My goal is to find a shorter formulation "there risk [...] ABC [...] XYZ that unambiguously captures these two distinct meanings

Comment: I'm not sure ***risk*** is really the right word for the second meaning anyway. It means *a situation involving exposure to danger*, which works fine in, say, [*the risk of having a heart attack.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+risk+of+having+a+heart+attack%22) (having a heart attack is obviously a dangerous situation). But if the referent of ***risk*** is a *statement*, I can only interpret it as meaning it *would* be a bad situation ***if that statement were found to be true***. And I'd rather refer to that with something like *the **chance/s that** A causes B (is true).*